# Ajax error "Error: Access is denied." in IE11. window.XDomainRequest object is not available

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I am getting error **"Error: Access is denied."** in **IE11** during ajax request. I was trying to solve it by using `window.XDomainRequest` but it's also not available in IE11. Kindly help me.

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    crossDomain: false,
    url: "dataFile.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        alert('success')
    },
    error: function(ex) {
        alert(ex.statusText); //Giving error "Error: Access is denied." 
    }
});
```

Comment: Why could `XDomainRequest` be relevant? You have a relative URI so you aren't working Cross Domain.

Comment: Is this problem limited to Internet Explorer 11? Have you tried reproducing it on other browsers?

Comment: What URL scheme are you using to load the HTML document containing the JavaScript? HTTP? HTTPS? FILE?

Comment: Look at your browser's developer tools. Can you see your Ajax request in the Net tab? Is it formatted correctly? Does it get a response? Is the response correct? Is the status code right?

Comment: "I am getting error". My crystal ball is out for repairs... which error? Where? Callstacks?

Comment: Yeah, It's working on another browser. I am facing it in IE11.

Comment: I'm working on local machine with HTTP. I tried it to doing by using javascript but this error is encountering on line 

xhttp.open("GET", filename, false);
and no request is showing in Net tab of IE developer tool.

Answer (score 0):

Probably by now (more than a year after) you have found a solution, but just in case...
As others have noted you don't write enough details about the issue, but since I encountered just now something similar and I was searching for a solution, maybe these will help:

https://davidwalsh.name/iframe-permission-denied

Or this:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/908356